# Як перекласти з російської "пренебрежительно малый"?

Tags: переклад, from-russian

Як перекласти з російської "пренебрежительно малый"? Спроба це зробити, до прикладу:

> Цей фактор був зневажливо малим за своїм впливом?

Ось результати моїх пошуків:

[https://ru.glosbe.com/ru/uk/пренебрежительно%20малый](https://ru.glosbe.com/ru/uk/%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B6%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE%20%D0%BC%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8B%D0%B9)

[https://r2u.org.ua/s?w=пренебрежительно+малый&scope=all&dicts=all&highlight=on](https://r2u.org.ua/s?w=%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B6%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE+%D0%BC%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8B%D0%B9&scope=all&dicts=all&highlight=on)

Comment: Тільки _[пренебрежимо](https://ru.wiktionary.org/wiki/пренебрежимо) малый_, а не _[пренебрежительно](https://ru.wiktionary.org/wiki/пренебрежительно) малый_.

Comment: @Yola, а мене? :) https://chinese.stackexchange.com/users/752/bytebuster

Comment: @bytebuster зроблено

Answer (score 13):

**Нехтовно малий**

> [negligible](https://e2u.org.ua/s?w=negligible&dicts=all&highlight=on&filter_lines=on) = ['nɛglɪdʒəbl] нехто́вний, нехто́вно мали́й; незначни́й

Comment: було б добре додати сюди одразу й визначення слова "нехтовний" на підтвердження адекватності перекладу, а отже: для повноти відповіді.

Answer (score 9):

**Мізерний**
або
**Мізерно малий**

Зважаючи на контекст можна використовувати обидва варіанти перекладу.

**Мізерний** (який не має істотного значення, великої ваги; незначний) зазвичай використовують в художній літературі, наприклад:

1. Мале тоді смішне, коли воно мізерне, коли себе поставить над усе (В. Симоненко).
2. Самотність! Гордощі! Які слова нікчемні! За пишним одягом який мізерний зміст! (Рильський, І, 1956, 120).

**Мізерно малий** (відхилення від результату, яким зазвичай можна знехтувати) найчастіше можна зустріти в економічній статистиці, математичному моделюванні, чисельних методах та інших точних науках, наприклад:

1. Очевидно, навантаження стержня визначиться величиною Q = а3γ, де γ — щільність матеріалу вантажу; при цьому передбачається, що маса стрижня [мізерно мала](http://library.uipa.edu.ua/library/BD/VidannaKaf/5/1/%D0%A1D/20/10/14.htm) в порівнянні з масою вантажу.
2. Область прийнятних і допустимих ризик-рішень розташована між [мізерно малим](http://pid.atwebpages.com/otsenka-riska.html) і недозволено високим рівнями ризику.
3. Якщо мікрочастинки перебувають на великих відстанях одна від одної, сили взаємодії між ними [мізерно малі](https://studfiles.net/preview/5543883/page:3/).
4. Коли точністні можливості будівельно-монтажного виробництва обмежені, застосовують принцип [мізерно малого](https://injzashita.com/normi-ie-principi-rozraxunku-tochnostui-rozbivochnix-robuit.html) впливу помилок геодезичних вимірів на загальну помилку...
5. ...інтервал відхилення Δ становить близько ± 3 10 8 нанометра, а отже, зважаючи на таке [мізерно мале відхилення](https://docplayer.net/amp/75417963-Ministerstvo-osviti-i-nauki-ukrayini-visnik-kiyivskogo-nacionalnogo-universitetu-tehnologiy-ta-dizaynu-seriya-tehnichni-nauki-6-92-2015.html), можна вважати, що робоча точка Р 8 відтворює закон руху по прямій лінії.
6. Коефіцієнт розподілу хлордифенілфосфата [мізерно малий](http://chem.lnu.edu.ua/wp-content/uploads/2016/12/%D0%90%D0%BD%D1%96%D1%89%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BA%D0%BE_dis.pdf), а 4-нітрофенолята натрію і дифенілфосфата натрію (продукт гідролізу), навпаки, дуже великі, тобто концентраціями хлордифенілфосфата у воді [ХФ]в і 4-нітофенолята [НФ]о, дифенілфосфата [ФА]о в органічній фазі можна знехтувати, що дозволяє не враховувати їх у подальших викладках без шкоди для строгості зроблених висновків.
7. Ейнштейн приходить висновку, що Земля внаслідок [мізерно малого](https://sites.google.com/site/volodimirkupcak/home/10-klas/profilnij-riven-licej/mehanika/relativistska-mehanika/osnovni-naslidki-stv-ta-ieh-eksperimentalne-pidtverdzenna) переміщення впродовж часу, що тривав дослід, являла собою інерціальну систему відліку, тому встановити її рух було неможливим.

Comment: Замість фрази "пренебрежительно малый" в російській мові використовують "ничтожно малый".

Comment: А можете навести приклад використання, не написаний Вами, а що якесь стороннє джерело вживає (і чим солідніше джерело, тим краще)? Дякую.

Comment: Тлумачення із "Словника української мови" https://www.slovnyk.ua/index.php?swrd=мізерні
Який не має істотного значення, великої ваги; незначний. 

- Мені доручена доля моїх братів, а я думаю, .. як би збутися тільки свого, власного горя, - воно ж нікчемне, мізерне перед великим горем моєї бідної країни... (Стар., Облога.., 1961, 65); 
 Самотність! Гордощі! Які слова нікчемні! За пишним одягом який мізерний зміст! (Рильський, І, 1956, 120).

Comment: @RomanMikhol, дякую. Можете додати ці цитати прямо у відповідь? Хоча я, якщо чесно, мав на увазі приклади використання саме для «мізерне відхилення», але якщо їх немає, то краще так, ніж ніяк.

Comment: -1, *мізерно малий* - це не завжди такий, яким можна знехтувати.

Comment: @Sasha "пренебрежительно малый" - це російський вікісуржик, спрощення від "ничтожно малое отклонение, значением которого можно пренебречь". Математичне відхилення не буває "мізерним", може буди лише "мізерно малим".

Comment: @RomanMikhol, останній Ваш коментар точно до мене, а не до Yola?